# Kendo.Upload. Upload method doesn't fire onUpload event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload, cropper

When the Kendo Upload component is supposed to perform upload second time, the onUpload event handler is not fired.

I use kendo upload with the cropperjs (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md) to upload an image, crop it and then send to the server. If the image is too large, the server sends an error. A user is expected to select another crop area and send the image again. On the last step nothing happens.

Here the way to crop an image and fire uploading

```
        cropper.crop();
        var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();

        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
            image = blob;
            $("#file").data("kendoUpload").upload();
        });
```

Then in the onUpload handler the initial incropped image is replaced with cropped one.

```
    e.data = {
        file: image,
        userName: $("#User_Login").val()
    };
```

On the server sends me an error:

```
public virtual ActionResult UpdateUserImage([FromBody]HttpPostedFileBase file, [FromBody]string userName)
        {
            try
            {
                ImageHelper.CheckImage(file);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new LargeJsonResult(new
                {
                    error = e.Message,
                })
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed
                };
            }
           ...
        }
```

The error is processed in the onError process handler:

```
        var err = e.XMLHttpRequest;
        if (err.status === 412) {
            var body = JSON.parse(err.response);
            alert(body.error);
        }
        else {
            alert("Unable to upload the file. Please check that the 
                        size is less than 10Mb.");
        }
```

After that the user is allowed to crop the already selected image. And after changing the cropped area the steps described above is expected to be repeated. But after `$("#file").data("kendoUpload").upload();` in the first code block nothing happens. However, I expect the onUpload event handler has to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)
Instead of sending an image to the server and check the size there, I check the size on the client and prevent sending if required. 
I mean before calling `$("#file").data("kendoUpload").upload();` I call

```
           if (image.size > 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
                alert("File is too big!");
                return;
            }
```

An everything is OK.
But, if somebody still has any idea why `$("#file").data("kendoUpload").upload();` doesn't fire the onUpload event handler, it would be great to share thoughts with me :)